# Error on Serialization

Tags: arrays, json, swift

I'm getting this error when I try to proceed on parsing the JSON. Does anyone know what I gotta do to fix it?

> **Error 1**:  Cannot subscript a value of type 'AudiobookJSON' (aka '`Array<Dictionary<String, Any>>`') with an index of type 'String'

[Error on Print](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1dnys.png)

File Model: Audiobook.swift:

```
import Foundation


struct Audiobook : Codable {
    let id: Int
    let descricao: String
    let urlImagem: String

    init(dictionary: AudiobookJSON) {
        self.id = dictionary["id"] as! Int//////ERROR MESSAGE ////////
        self.descricao = dictionary["descricao"] as! String/////ERROR MESSAGE
        self.urlImagem = dictionary["urlImagem"] as! String////ERROR MESSAGE
    }

}
```

Folder Networking: APIClient.swift:

```
import Foundation

typealias AudiobookJSON = [[String: Any]]

struct APIClient {

    static func getAudiobooksAPI(completion: @escaping ([Audiobook]?) -> Void) {

        let url = URL(string: "https://alodjinha.herokuapp.com/categoria")

        let session = URLSession.shared

        guard let unwrappedURL = url else { print("Error unwrapping URL"); return }

        let dataTask = session.dataTask(with: unwrappedURL) { (data, response, error) in

            guard let unwrappedDAta = data else { print("Error unwrapping data"); return }

            do {

                //let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: unwrappedDAta, options: .allowFragments) as! [String:Any]
                //let posts = json["data"] as? AudiobookJSON
                let posts = try JSONDecoder().decode([Audiobook].self, from: unwrappedDAta)

                print(posts)



                completion(posts)

            } catch {
                print("Could not get API data. \(error), \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
        }
        dataTask.resume()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I can see that `AudiobookJSON` is an array of key-value pairs that's why you are getting error: So you have to use codable like that:

First: you have to make Codable type struct like that(your codable struct variable names should be same as you are getting in response):

```
struct Audiobook: Codable {
    let id: Int?
    let descricao: String?
    let urlImagem: String?

}
```

Second: when you get the response then parse directly using codale like that:

```
guard let unwrappedDAta = data else { print("Error unwrapping data"); return }

do {

    let posts = try JSONDecoder().decode([Audiobook].self, from: unwrappedDAta)

    print(posts)
    completion(posts)

} catch let message {
    print("JSON serialization error:" + "\(message)")
}
```

You can directly use the response like:

```
for audio in posts {
  print("audio.id")
  print("audio.descricao")
  print("audio.urlImagem")
}
```